# All fields in my guestbook show up blank

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to use a tutorial to create a guestbook, but the only data actually transferring to my guestbook is the date and time.

I have a database set up as:

Id|Name|Email|Comment|Datetime

I have 3 pages:

addguestbook.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="foo"; // Mysql username 
$password="bar"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="foo"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

$sql="INSERT INTO guestbook(Name, Email, Comment, Datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//check if query successful 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";

// link to view guestbook page
echo "<a href='viewguestbook.php'>View guestbook</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

guestbook.php

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><strong>Test Sign Guestbook </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="addguestbook.php">
<td>
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="117">Name</td>
<td width="14">:</td>
<td width="357"><input name='name' type="text" id="name" size="40" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name='email' type="text" id="email" size="40" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Comment</td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name='comment' cols="40" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><strong><a href="viewguestbook.php">View Guestbook</a> </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

& viewguestbook.php

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><strong>View Guestbook | <a href="guestbook.php">Sign Guestbook</a> </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>

<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="foo"; // Mysql username 
$password="bar"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="foo"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="117">Name</td>
<td width="14">:</td>
<td width="357"><? echo $rows['Name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['Email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Comment</td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['Comment']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Date/Time </td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['Datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
}
mysql_close(); //close database
?>
```

The viewguestbook.php works fine, just no data is actually going into my database other than the dates..

Comment: You never set `$name` and the like, which means you're probably assuming that `register_globals` is on. Horrible assumption. register_globals was an incredibly moronic idea that should never have gotten past the cocktail napkin stage, and has rightfully been ripped out of PHP. it's currently being chopped into very very very small bits prior to being set on fire.

Comment: which also means you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: where does your `<form>` begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not retrieving the form fields when you insert them:

```
$datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time
$sql="INSERT INTO guestbook(Name, Email, Comment, Datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";
```

The only reason that the datetime goes in is because you actually get it first. You need to get $name, $email, and $comment from your form like:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

before the insert. And on a side note, your HTML for your table/form is invalid. You can't just inject a form into the middle of a table.

Comment: THANK YOU! God I'm a moron sometime, that was it. All fixed now, thank you so much!